# hadoop namenode not getting detected

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to configure a pseudo hadoop 1 node cluster on my ubuntu machine. However when i give the following command

bin/start-all.sh

it start all the daemons but when i do jps,it does not give me namnode port and when i go to the namenode logs
The following message is displayed.

```
2013-04-26 11:59:09,927 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs://vikasXXX.XX.XX.XX:X000
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Trash.<init>(Trash.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.startTrashEmptier(NameNode.java:314)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:496)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1279)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1288)

2013-04-26 11:59:09,929 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at vikas/XXX.XX.XX.XX
************************************************************/
```

What could be the reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you have masked and shared your URL

`hdfs://vikasXXX.XX.XX.XX:X000`

I think it is not recognizing your machine by name. Try using localhost and check if it works.

`hdfs://localhost:8020`

Comment: I m facing the same issue over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944556/unable-to-start-namenode-for-hadoop-in-cygwin but cant find a solution